# Disable prompt to convert videos copied to media device

Tags: windows-7, media-player, mobile-phone

I have a Samsung Galaxy S II, which when connected to my Windows 7 computer acts as a "Portable Media Player"

[image: GT-I9100 Portable Media Player]

Whenever I try to copy a video onto the device, it prompts if I want to convert it, like so:

[image: Do you want to convert <video> before it's copied to your device?]

This gets quite annoying in the long run, so I'd like to disable it.

Is there a way to disable these prompts?

Comment: I think what I did with my N8 was connect it in mass storage mode so Windows would treat it as a standard flash drive. For the SII try `Applications` > `Development` > `USB debugging`.

Comment: It is almost always faster and less problematic to connect these devices as "Mass Storage" if the syncing is not nessisary, When your just trying to copy files, and you know the files are formatted for the device.

Comment: @Bob: I don't believe I can do that since I've switched to Android 4. USB debugging is enabled, but it doesn't put it into mass storage mode as it did in 2.3.5, and it only lets me pick one of "Media Device (MTP)" or "Camera (PTP)" for connection mode.

Comment: Answers below are outdated, because recent Android no longer supports Mass Storage mode. And it seems that those smart Microsoft engineers never expected that people would be annoyed when they have to deal with that unnecessary confirmation dialogue each time. Does anyone know any alternative MTP transfer application on Windows? Something similar to an FTP program but in MTP.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Why this happens

That prompt is one of the features Windows implements for devices connected as [MTP devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol). The most sure way to disable it is to connect your Galaxy SII in USB Mass Storage mode. This way, Windows will detect it as a normal flash drive and will transfer files like any other flash drive without caring about the type. Some (desired) more advanced functionality may be lost, however.

The two basic ways to stop this from happening:

- Connect the phone in Mass Storage mode.
- Disable the shell extension on Windows that handles this. There are two ways to do *this*:

  - Unregister the `.dll`.
  - Disable the extension with ShellExView.

---

## Option 1: Changing the phone connection mode

Enabling Mass Storage mode on Galaxy SII ICS (Android 4.x) ([source](http://www.jayceooi.com/2012/03/14/how-to-enable-usb-mass-storage-on-android-4-0-ics-samsung-galaxy-s2/)):

> 1. Bring up Settings.
> 2. Click More… (under Wireless and network).
> 3. Then select USB utilities ~ Set USB cable connection mode.
> 4. Select Connect storage to PC then.
> 5. Connect USB cable from phone to PC.
> 6. Select Turn on USB storage.
>      That’s all.

---

## Option 2: Unregistering the `.dll` for the Windows shell extension that handles this

If you wish to keep using MTP mode for whatever reason, [there has been a thread created on microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-sound/stop-windows-7-from-prompting-convert-and-copy/08565846-904b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) specifically addressing disabling this prompt. Specifically:

> Well, I previously couldn't find references to that dialog in any
>   Windows 7 DLL file, so I thought that it wasn't Windows-related. But I
>   have now looked again and found references to it in wpdshext.dll. So
>   it does appear to be a standard Windows feature, my apologies.
>
> I suggest that you try unregistering the DLL in question. Please open
>   the Start Menu, go to All Programs - Accessories, right-click Command
>   Prompt, and select Run as administrator. Then type the following
>   command:
>
> regsvr32 /u wpdshext.dll

You should probably restart after running the command.

I have not tried this method personally, and unregistering standard Windows DLLs may have unexpected consequences. If anything does go wrong, I recommend you start in Safe Mode and run `regsvr32 wpdshext.dll` in an elevated command prompt.

---

## Disabling the shell extension

This method may be safer than unregistering a `.dll`.

1. Download [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
2. Find the extension named `Portable Devices Menu`
3. Right click > `Disable Selected Items`
4. Restart your computer (to be safe)

Comment: He didn't ask how to connect in MS mode, he asked how to disable the prompt.

Comment: @Mark Connecting in Mass Storage mode is a definite way to disable the prompt. In other words, he can transfer videos without the prompt, the desired result. This answers the question, albeit at the cost of other MTP functionality/advantages. I did mention that in the original answer. However, I did just dig up a source mentioning disabling the Convert dialog specifically while (presumably) keeping other MTP functionality, and have added that to the answer.

Comment: Now I can upvote your answer! Generally, the advantages of MTP (the major one being that the storage in question does not need to be unmounted from the device first) outweight the disadvantages. Only when the absolute highest speed is required is MS mode better.

Comment: I had a similar problem, with Windows asking whether I really wanted to copy my flac music to the phone. Unregistering wpdshext.dll did not solve the problem.

By the way, my Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.4 only allows me to choose between MTP mode and PTP mode, there is no option to mount it as USB mass storage device.

Comment: @RuudvA Try [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and make sure the "Portable Devices Menu" extension is disabled. As for your phone, you may have more luck asking how to enable Mass Storage Mode for a Galaxy Nexus on the [Android.SE site](http://android.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I did disable the shell extension, but it did not remove the prompt either.

Comment: none of those solution worked for me on windows 8. first solution doesn't exist, and the rest i've tried and nothing changed.

Comment: I wouldn't have even mentioned un-registering the DLL as an option - seems risky and not guaranteed to work. Using ShellExView seems like the much better option. Thanks!

Comment: None of these methods work

Comment: @monstro Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there's an officially supported option. The AHK script moneytoo provided might be the best option you can get.

Comment: Neither unregistering the dll nor using ShellExView do work on a current Windows 7 64bit edition. Even with admin permissions one can see in Process Monitor `ACCESS_DENIED` entries when performing these steps. Via regedit you can take over ownership over certain registry keys and then delete it.

Comment: @Robert In that case, an alternative is to run as `SYSTEM` (via `PsExec -s`). Or maybe TrustedInstaller.

Comment: @Bob: I noticed that anyway unregistering wpdshext.dll is not a solution because it removes the MTP access completely.

Comment: @Robert ah, perhaps older devices fell back to mass storage. I'll have to test and update this answer sometime. I do vaguely recall it working though.

Comment: The "Why This Happens" section doesn't really say why this happens. Why DOES it happen? What is the difference if you say yes or no?

Comment: @Dronz It happens because you have your device plugged in in MTP mode, and this is how Windows reacts to MTP devices. This question is asking how to disable it, and I have answered that along of a description of why it appears. If you want to know why Microsoft specifically decided to implement this functionality, or the what exactly it does, that is outside the scope of this question and you should ask a new one. I'm not here to write an extended essay on the purposes of MTP nor the intricacies of the implementation.

Answer (score 5):

As nothing mentioned works for me on Windows 8.1, here's alternative approach using a script in [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

```
dlgTitle := "Copy"
dlgBtnUnwantedAction := "No, skip this file"
dlgBtnWantedAction := "Yes"
dlgTitleAlt := "Convert and Copy"
dlgBtnUnwantedActionAlt := "Yes, convert and copy (recommended)"
dlgBtnWantedActionAlt := "No, just copy"
dlgBtnCancel := "Cancel"
GroupAdd, dlgTitles, %dlgTitle% ahk_class #32770
GroupAdd, dlgTitles, %dlgTitleAlt% ahk_class #32770

SetTitleMatchMode 3
matchFound := false

Loop
{
    WinWait ahk_group dlgTitles
    matchFound := false

    ControlGetText, button1Text, Button1, ahk_group dlgTitles
    if ( button1Text = dlgBtnUnwantedAction || button1Text = dlgBtnUnwantedActionAlt ) {
        ControlGetText, button2Text, Button2, ahk_group dlgTitles
        if ( button2Text = dlgBtnWantedAction || button2Text = dlgBtnWantedActionAlt ) {
            ControlGetText, button3Text, Button3, ahk_group dlgTitles
            if ( button3Text = dlgBtnCancel ) {
                matchFound := true
            }
        }       
    }

    if ( matchFound ) {
        ControlClick, Button2, ahk_group dlgTitles
    } else {
        WinWaitClose ahk_group dlgTitles
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Years later... there may be a way.
Open regedit as administrator and head to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\
```

Backup this "FormatMap".

Next, we'll try to fool Windows...
Basically, you'll have to copy the content of "Format" and "ContentType" keys from a format to another.

Try to use these source formats :

```
.gif, .bmp for images (jpeg, png...) :
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.gif]
"Format"="{38070000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{EF2107D5-A52A-4243-A26B-62D4176D7603}"

.wma for audio (mp3,mp4, aac, flac...) :
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.wma]
"Format"="{B9010000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{4AD2C85E-5E2D-45E5-8864-4F229E3C6CF0}"

.wmv for video (avi mp4...) :
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.wmv]
"Format"="{B9810000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{9261B03C-3D78-4519-85E3-02C5E1F50BB9}"

.doc, .xls, .ppt for documents or other files :
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.doc]
"Format"="{BA830000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{680ADF52-950A-4041-9B41-65E393648155}"
```

e.g., the original key for flac is

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.flac]
"Format"="{B9060000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{4AD2C85E-5E2D-45E5-8864-4F229E3C6CF0}"
```

So we'll just change it to WMA's ID:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.flac]
"Format"="{B9010000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{4AD2C85E-5E2D-45E5-8864-4F229E3C6CF0}"
```

We could also add new formats, like .m4a (audio mp4) :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Portable Devices\FormatMap\.m4a]
"Format"="{B9010000-AE6C-4804-98BA-C57B46965FE7}"
"ContentType"="{4AD2C85E-5E2D-45E5-8864-4F229E3C6CF0}"
```

However, it may have unwanted effects on any app using theses keys... Maybe WMP ?

Comment: As you yourself said, it has unwanted effects. Definitely. You must not "fix" annoyance by making it a technical problem.

Comment: I haven't noticed unwanted effects (yet), but I don't use WMP to listen to music. Moreover, my phone isn't recognized by WMP, so I can't try the "sync" feature.
I found out it works for file transfer, but I didn't do additional tests and my computer still runs fine. 
The only possible problems I can imagine are with WMP or the way Windows analyze media devices for autorun. 
Sometimes we have to choose between two annoyances... What were yours ?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to just patch **wpdshext.dll**

On my system (Windows 7 x64, with WMP not installed) the function that opens the confirmation box is

```
long __cdecl CObjectPropertyChecker::_DoesObjectMatchDeviceCapabilities(int)
```

which returns `0` if the copy is allowed, otherwise `1`.

I just replaced the first few bytes of the function with:

```
xor rax,rax
ret
```

so it always returns `0`.

Working well so far; I'll report back if I notice any unexpected results.

---

for reference, the CRC of my **wpdshext.dll** was `d6ca5ac8`, before patching

and `_DoesObjectMatchDeviceCapabilities` is at RVA `0x95118`

Comment: Thanks.

What's a good tool to do this?

Alternatively, could you upload your patched file somewhere?

Comment: i suggest x64dbg, since you can attach to explorer, go to *Symbols* → *Module* 'wpdshext.dll' → *Download symbols …*, which makes it easy to find the function to patch.

Answer (score -1):

For those of you having trouble getting any of these technical suggestions to work (like me) I found a workaround. Just make a new folder on your PC desktop and copy into it all the files you want to transfer to your device. Then, once that is done, just drag the whole folder onto your device to copy it across as usual. The prompt will appear, but you can just select "do this for all files" and it will transfer across the entire contents of the folder without prompting you again.