# wpdshext.dll - what does it do?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I've recently come across a problem where by whenever I try and transfer a media file via MTP to any capable device, I get the following error

```
"Your device might not be able play or view this file."
```

From a similar [thread,](https://superuser.com/questions/402225/disable-prompt-to-convert-videos-copied-to-media-device)  it looks as if this could possibly be related to the above file (`wpdshext.dll`). (although it's a somewhat different message, it's similar enough to make me think the two are part of the same component) However, after following both sets of instructions in the above thread, I'm still getting the error.

So, I guess I've got two questions

1. Does anyone know what `wpdshext.dll` actually does? It's description in Properties isn't too revealing...
2. Does anyone know how I can disable this extremely annoying message every time I attempt and copy a media file to my device?

Btw, this is on Windows 7 Home Premium X64.

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a report on that dll: http://www.win7dll.info/wpdshext_dll.html

Comment: Thanks for that link. It looks as if most of the strings in the DLL relate to copying media files to devices - however, the message that appears when copying a file over MTP doesn't seem to be there. Plus, the "Open as Device" option still appears in the right-click context menu after the DLL has been unregistered with Regsvr32. Any ideas? Are standard Microsoft DLLs prevented from unregistering?

Comment: It could be a result of a function called from any of the other DLLs that this one pulls. If the dll is unregistered, then the error is probably coming from a different dll call, one that maybe windows defaults to if this particular one is missing.